# Xpath Query on HTML page - syntax?

Tags: php, xpath

I have this URL:-

http://ask.recipelabs.com/users

and I wish to find the highest page number in the div id 'pager' (in this case it is 7)

I have tried this but it returns zero:

```
function getusers($url)
{
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//span[@class="page-numbers"]');
echo 'there are ', $nodelist->length, ' span elements having class="page-numbers"';
}
```

Is my syntax incorrect? I was then hoping to step through the array and find the highest number.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: directly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595072/extract-value-from-web-page

Comment: does the page validate as xml? If it doesn't XPath will likely not find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(//span[@class="page-numbers"][number(.) > 0])[last()]
```

This gives you the one last node that still has a number as it's contents.

Comment: that doesn't appear to work - could you try it with he URL I included and the full function I supplied?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using

```
$doc->loadhtml($url);
```

And unless $url is badly named, it is a string containing a URL, not HTML.  Such a string parses a pretty much an empty DOM, certainly not one with all the expected XPath, et voila...

Maybe you meant `$doc = loadHTMLFile($url);`  ?